# script to find pagerank of domain

Tags: python, api, pagerank

how can I automate finding the pagerank of a domain? I came across [this Python script](http://blogmag.net/blog/read/91/Python_code_to_check_your_Google_PageRank) but it no longer works. Seems Google doesn't like people automating this.

So, is there an alternative provider of page rank scores? I do not need the exact same result as Google, but something comparable.

Comment: why the script you posted doesn't work anymore? I assume you would just have to do query with link:siteaddress (http://www.google.com/help/cheatsheet.html) to get the number of links to a page, then do it recursively.
Consider that many websites don't like to be scanned by spiders and that you should ask permission to the webmaster to do so.

Comment: yeah I'm not intending to do the computation myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a python script [which does work](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/221/).  I had to do exactly the same thing recently!

Comment: you're right - it works! Google must have updated that hash algorithm, which broke the earlier script.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried HalOtis Marketing's Page Rank script at http://www.halotis.com/2009/08/02/google-page-range-python-script/? He generally writes good, simple Python code for exactly this kind of stuff.

Comment: actually that is the same script - he copied it from the example I gave

Comment: Ah, I see that now. HalOtis even mentions it in the first line of the blog post. Guess I should read a little closer!